# How to cancel jquery execution upon action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table displaying rows of records.

The goal is for the user to hover their mouse over any given row for 1 second, display a popup with a loading animation, and load the popup with various info about that record. If they mouse over another records, it will remove the original popup and start the process anew.

The problem I'm having is controlling when to stop the execution of these record detail calls. If I hover my mouse over various records before the previous one fully loads, when I finally do stop moving my mouse the popup cycles through all the records previously requested.

I ideally I need the execution to stop when the mouse leaves the record row. Also, execution should stop and the popup should hide upon clicking the record row, as clicking the row performs other actions.

My code so far:

```
        var timeout;

        $("#tblQueueItems tr").mouseenter(function (cRow) {
            var cRowCopy = $(this);
            cRowCopy.addClass('hover');
            hideBox();
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                hideBox();
                var orderId = cRowCopy.attr('oid');
                showBox("<div id='divLoading'><img src='/images/AjaxLoader.gif' /></div>", RowCopy, cRow);
                $.get('/api/WorkQueue/GetWQIOrderModal', { orderId: orderId }, function (data) {
                    showBox(data, cRowCopy, cRow);
                });
            }, 1000);

            cRowCopy.mouseleave(function () {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                cRowCopy.removeClass('hover');
            });

            cRowCopy.click(function () {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                hideBox();
                cRowCopy.removeClass('hover');
            });

        });

        $("#divOrderPopup").mouseenter(function () {
            var orderId = $("[id^=hf_]").attr('id').split("_").pop();
            $("#tr_" + orderId).addClass('hover');
        });

        $("#divOrderPopupMoving").mouseleave(function () {
            var orderId = $("[id^=hf_]").attr('id').split("_").pop();
            $("#tr_" + wqiId).removeClass('hover');
            hideBox();
        });
    }

    function showBox(text, obj, e) {
        var left = (e.pageX + 25) + 'px';
        var top = (e.pageY - 200) + 'px';
        var node = "<div style=\"z-index: 25;background: #ffffff;width: 715px;padding: 10px;border: 2px solid black;\" id=\"popBox\">";
        node += text;
        node += "</div>";
        $("#divOrderPopup").css('position', 'absolute');
        $("#divOrderPopup").css('top', top);
        $("#divOrderPopup").css('left', left);
        $("#divOrderPopup").html(node);
    }

    function hideBox() {
        window.node = document.getElementById('popBox');
        $("#divOrderPopupMoving").html('');
        window.on = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save your AJAX request to a variable, for example to a global one:

```
req =  $.get('/api/WorkQueue/GetWQIOrderModal', { orderId: orderId }, function (data) {
                    showBox(data, cRowCopy, cRow);
                });
```

and on mouseleave you can call `req.abort()` :

```
   $("#divOrderPopupMoving").mouseleave(function () {
        req.abort();
        var orderId = $("[id^=hf_]").attr('id').split("_").pop();
        $("#tr_" + wqiId).removeClass('hover');
        hideBox();
    });
```

I think this was your question/problem so far because you didn't told us where you stuck.

Comment: If I assign my .get to a global variable, how do I trigger it at the appropriate time, inside my timeout function? Also, how could I define the parameters outside the scope of knowing which row is currently hovered over? This solution looks close to solving my problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you quite correct. You don't need to trigger the AJAX request. The variable will just keep the `jqXHR object`
, the request itself will start as usual. To your second point: you could use a global variable too.

Comment: The request uses parameters unknown until the table row properties are discovered, which change as the user moves their mouse among them. I am unsure how to make my request known to my other mouse events to even be able to stop the previous request. If I move my request outside the mouseenter event, the request parameters are unknown

Comment: Yes, leave the request were it is. Just save it to a global variable and add the req.abort() to mouseleave.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've added 'var request;' next to my 'var timeout;' I then assigned variable request = the $.get call. Everything is working exactly as intended! Thank you very much